# Could not find method implementation () for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I ran into a failed grade build problem after installing dart and flutter in my Android studio project. I tried creating a new flutter app but it kept on building forever so I had to stop it. On restarting Android studio my grade has refused to build for every existing project I have.

**Error Message**

```
Gradle sync failed: This Gradle plugin requires a newer IDE able to request IDE model level 3. For Android Studio this means version 3.0+
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

**app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
}
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionName '3.1'
    testInstrumentationRunner 
  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    android {
        defaultConfig {

        }
    }
    versionCode 1
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.2'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
implementation 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.15'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Thu Feb 21 22:53:26 WAT 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

Comment: is `noinspection GradleCompatible` a typo?

Comment: It's a comment actually

Answer (score 1):

First, you have incorrect line your **app** build.gradle (bases on your question), The correct one should be something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// You don't need a repository here

android {
  signingConfigs {
  }
  compileSdkVersion 28
  buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionName '3.1'
    testInstrumentationRunner
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    android {
      defaultConfig {
      }
    }
    versionCode 1
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
          'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  productFlavors {
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

  androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })


  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

  implementation 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'
  implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
  implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.15'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Then you need to update your **root** `build.gradle` because `implementation` is only available for android build.gradle version 3.0. :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
 }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

You also need to update your gradle version to 4.1

Please take a details in [Android Gradle plugin release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-plugin)

Comment: I've done all the changes and now I get this error: This grade plugin requires a newer IDE able to request IDE model level 3. For Android studio this means version 3.0+ My Android studio version is 2.3.3

Comment: Well, if you're android studio is still version 2.3.3, you can't use the `implementation`. So, change `implementation` to `compile` and `androidTestImplementation` to `androidTestCompile`

Comment: Changed all implementation to compile still didn't work. Give this error. Could not find method Android Test compile() for arguments [com.android.supporr.test.espresso-core:2.2.2, build_......

Comment: And also I've been using implementation with the Android studio version befor this issue came up. I don't think changing to compile would really have solved it. Something just doesn't seem right and I can't just figure it out. Please help

Comment: okay, there should be something broken in your `build.gradle`. Can you update your question with your current project and app `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue I have made changes in File--> Project structure --> Project settings --> Project mention the latest android version on the system it was 30 in my case.
Same is also done for Platform Settings --> SDK mentioned android and correct the JAVA Home path and then in code also I have done below changes and it worked for me.
Change GradleException to FileNotFoundException and then I am able to compile.

```
//throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
```

Answer (score -1):

Fix the problem by downloading android studio 3.0+ with this link https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html